# code on external javascript file not working properly

Tags: javascript

```
    (function foo() {
        alert('Hello World!');
        setTimeout(foo,1000);
    })();
```

i have written a function like that. when i put that function inside my HTML page within  tag this function works properly. but when i put this function to an external javascript file and link that file to my web page this function executes only once(the alert pops up only once). i mean the     setTimeout(foo,1000);
doesn't seem to have any effect.

where is the problem and how can i get rid of this? [but other functions on my js file works properly.]

Comment: Does you external file contain only the above code? What other functions do you have in your js file?

Comment: Can u also show the HTML - where JS is referenced and where it is called?

Comment: Do you have other code in that file ?

Comment: not sure but for me the code inside () will not generate a function that setTimeout can reach ... did you tested this way ? function foo() {alert('Hello World!'); setTimeout(foo,1000); } foo();

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED:**

I think you need just wrapping out into closure function like that:

```
(function() {
    function foo(){
      console.log('Hello, world!', new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
      setTimeout(foo,1000);
    }

    window.onload = foo;
})();
```

Little bit [theory and examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#JavaScript).

Comment: This is functionally different; `foo` will only run once. Also, named function expressions get a reference to themselves. There is no need for an additional closure.